# Arduino send data to Android using HC-05

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

**What I have :**

HC-05 Bluetooth module

Arduino promini

BPM sensors

Android studio 3.0

**What I have done :**

Connect the Arduino, sensors, and HC-05 bluetooth using Serial

Send the data from Arduino script

Recieve and get the data using 3rd party apps from playstore

**What I wanted to do :**
Get the data from arduino's to be showed in the android text view, using native coded apps (not the one from the store) using android studio.

My current code :

Arduino script :

```
loop(){
  Serial.println("*"+String(BPM)+"#"); //BPM from sensor
  delay(200)
}
```

And some code for connecting and pairing using Android Bluetooth Adapter, which I can't showed here full because still hard coded, but the point is :

I made a handler, which recieves incoming inputs from the serial, and at least showing them on Toast component, but still haven't managed to make it work.

```
h = new Handler() {

        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case RECIEVE_MESSAGE:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Data in",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show();// if receive massage
                    byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                    String strIncom = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);                 // create string from bytes array
                    sb.append(strIncom);                                                // append string
                    int endOfLineIndex = sb.indexOf("\r\n");                            // determine the end-of-line
                    if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {                                            // if end-of-line,
                        String sbprint = sb.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);               // extract string
                        sb.delete(0, sb.length());                                      // and clear
                        sensorView0.setText("Data from Arduino: " + sbprint);            // update TextView
                        btnOff.setEnabled(true);
                        btnOn.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                    //Log.d(TAG, "...String:"+ sb.toString() +  "Byte:" + msg.arg1 + "...");
                    break;
            }
        };
    };
```

I also have a class :

```
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
        // member streams are final
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) { }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[256];  // buffer store for the stream
        int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
        while (true) {
            try {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Masuk ke handler private class",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show();
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);        // Get number of bytes and message in "buffer"
                h.obtainMessage(RECIEVE_MESSAGE, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();     // Send to message queue Handler
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Which I think calls for the handler to read the message, but haven't managed to make it work.

I wanted to at least show the message to the Toast, or TextView, but haven't got a clear answer this last 3 weeks.
So anyone who can help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can't carry out a UI operation, i.e, showing a `Toast`, directly from a thread. You need to put the code in `runOnUiThread`.

Comment: Also, the ideal thing to do would be to use an `ASyncTask`. The thread code goes in `doInBackground` and the handler code goes in `onProgressUpdate`.